# C#: Get the sha1 of the last commit in git repo?

Tags: c#, git, ngit

I'm trying to create somewhat of a version tag with `branch:sha1`.

I've managed to get the branch name, but I can't get the last commits sha1?

It should be fairly similar to JGit for Java as its a port of it, but I can't see any way the API is exposing this?

Here is what I have:

```
var repository = NGit.Api.Git.Open(Directory.GetParent(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)?.Parent?.Parent?.Parent?.Parent?.FullName);
var branch = repository.GetRepository().GetBranch();
var sha1 = "";

Console.WriteLine($"{branch}:{sha1}");
```

Comment: Which exact library are you using? I'd personally recommend using LibGit2Sharp - I know the NuGet package is only marked as preview, but it's been very reliable for me, and is well-used.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm using NGit, although I'll take a look at your suggestion.

Comment: https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/NGit.Api/Git/-/php-git-class-examples.html

Comment: Do you mean [this package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ngit), that was last updated in 2011?

Comment: @JonSkeet yes, I've since answered this with LibGit2Sharp as ngit seems outdated.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to John Skeet's comment recommending LibGit2Sharp, here is how to do it:

```
var directory = Directory.GetParent(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)?.Parent
    ?.Parent
    ?.Parent
    ?.Parent
    ?.FullName;

using (var repo = new Repository(directory))
{
    var branch = repo.Head.FriendlyName;
    var sha1 = repo.Head.Commits.Last().Sha;
    
    Console.WriteLine($"{branch}:{sha1}");
}
```